# Behavior of a simple numerical iteration

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

Say I have a simple fixed point iteration problem $x_{k+1}=g(x_k)=\frac{1}{2}(x_k^2+c)$, $0<c<1$. If the fixed points are $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$, then $0<\xi_1<1<\xi_2$. Since $|g'(\xi_1)|<1$, this fixed point is stable and $\xi_2$ is unstable. Now convergence to $\xi_1$ happens if the starting iterate $x_0$ is taken to be $0\le x_0< \xi_2$. How does this range for $x_0$ come about? What happens if $x_0<0$?

Comment: Sorry, I thought your question was what happens if $x_0\lt0$ (to which the answer is "the same as for $-x_0$") – I didn't realize the question before that was meant as an independent question. I've deleted my answer.

Comment: @joriki do you think it's because $\xi_2$ is unstable. so when $x_0>\xi_2$, it diverges and when $x_0<\xi_2$, it diverges but converges to the nearby stable fixed point $\xi_1$?

Comment: I think so, in general terms, but I haven't thought about the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\ 0\le x_k< \xi_1\ $, then $\ 0< \frac{1}{2} \left(\xi_1+x_k\right)<\frac{1}{2}\ $, and so
\begin{align}
\xi_1 - x_{k+1}&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\xi_1^2 -x_k^2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\xi_1 - x_k\right)\left(\xi_1+x_k\right)\ .
\end{align}
It follows from this that $\ x_k< \xi_1-\frac{1}{2}\left(\xi_1-x_k\right) <x_{k+1}<\xi_1\ $, and hence, by induction, whenever $\ 0\le x_0<\xi_1\ $, that
$$
\xi_1-\frac{1}{2^k} \left(\xi_1-x_0\right)<x_{k+1}<\xi_1\ ,
$$
from which it follows that $\ x_n\rightarrow\xi_1\ $ as  $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $.

Similarly, if $\ \xi_1<x_k<\xi_2\ $, then
\begin{align}
x_{k+1}-\xi_1&=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_k^2-\xi_1^2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_k-\xi_1\right)\left(x_k+ \xi_1\right)\\
&< x_k-\xi_1\ ,
\end{align}
since $\ \xi_1+\xi_2=2\ $.   It follows by induction that $\ \xi_1<x_{k+1}<x_0\ $ whenever $\ \xi_1<x_0<\xi_2\ $, and then that
$$
\xi_1< x_{k+1}< \xi_1+\left(\frac{x_0+\xi_1}{2}\right)^k  \left(x_0-\xi_1\right)\ ,
$$
from which it again follows that  $\ x_n\rightarrow\xi_1\ $ as  $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $.

On the other hand, if $\ x_0>\xi_2\ $, then
\begin{align}
x_1-\xi_2&=\frac{1}{2} \left(x_0-\xi_2\right)\left(x_0+ \xi_2\right)\\
&>x_0-\xi_2\ .
\end{align}
Therefore, $\ x_1>x_0\ $, and again by induction we get
$$
x_{k+1}-\xi_2> \left(\frac{x_0+\xi_2}{2}\right)^k  \left(x_0-\xi_2\right)\ ,
$$
from which it follows that $\ x_n\ $ diverges to $\ +\infty\ $ as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $ in this case.